# Dynamic Arrays of type memory

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethereum-design, mastering-ethereum

Are the dynamic arrays of type memory fixed sized. I have read that the arrays of type memory are fixed sixed.

Thanks

Comment: I assume your question is about Solidity. In that case, yes. You cannot resize an in-memory array in Solidity, so their size is "fixed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CryptoZombies](https://cryptozombies.io/) tutorial has a clear snippet on this:

https://github.com/loomnetwork/cryptozombie-lessons/blob/master/en/3/11-savinggasstorage.md#declaring-arrays-in-memory

> Note: memory arrays must be created with a length argument (in this
>   example, 3). They currently cannot be resized like storage arrays can
>   with array.push(), although this may be changed in a future version of
>   Solidity.

The same is reiterated directly in the Solidity documentation:

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays

> As opposed to storage arrays, it is not possible to resize memory arrays by assigning to the .length member.